# fixed div within nav but only on overflow scroll?

Tags: css

I have a cart that pops out from the side of the screen when clicking the cart button.  If too many items are put into the cart, the bottom got cut off.  So I added overflow:auto and that's fine.  But... the "checkout" button that is below the cart items gets pushed below the fold and it could be confusing.  So I wanted to make the checkout button to be fixed at the bottom, but only when necessary.

Any idea how to do that?

the site is here:  [removed] and if you add all the items on that page to the cart and then click the cart icon, hopefully you'll see what I mean.

This is a zen-cart installation with a custom template that I paid a guy to make.  I'm just trying to tweak it a bit.  I'm by no means a css expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow: auto;` from `cbp-spmenu` class and try this

```
.panel-div2
{

    max-height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: wth man... how'd you do that?  That's even better than I wanted.  Only thing is the scroll bar looks funny with a gap between it and the main one.  But otherwise perfect!  Thanks.

Comment: I see how to get rid of the gap.  So no worries